# Wordpress xmlrpc directory request problem

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to list methods on my wordpress site with the following request

```
<methodCall>
<methodName>system.listMethods</methodName>
<params></params>
</methodCall>
```

after this I get the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name>
          <value><int>-32700</int></value>
        </member>
        <member>
          <name>faultString</name>
          <value><string>parse error. not well formed</string></value>
        </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Does this mean that the listing requests function is blocked or could there be another problem?I've also tried to use other requests but the response is always the same

Answer (score 0):

The `faultCode` `-32700` with the message "`parse error. not well formed`" is not particularly a sign that the listing of the functions requests or any other problem has been summoned by your XMLRPC request.

First of all it looks more particular to the underlying implementation. The [*Specification for Fault Code Interoperability, version 20010516*](https://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/specs/rfc.fault_codes.php) by Dan Libby (with major contributions from Charles Cook, Dave Winer, Eric Kidd, John Wilson and S. Alexander Jacobson) may suggest, particularly from the *Defined Error Codes*:

> -32700 ---> parse error. not well formed

, that this is standard error reporting not connected to any specific method implementation on that XMLRPC server.

It is a strong sign that the Wordpress XMLRPC server has received a request  from your XMLRPC client that could not be parsed. The *"not well formed"* part of the message is related to a well-formed document in XML; XMLRPC is using XML (as also its name may even already suggest).

The [XML 1.0 presentation slide #23](https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Offices/Presentations/XML1.0/slide23-0.htm) provides an overview, one important part here in context of the question is, that

> If the XML document is **not** well formed, programs using it must report an error

If we revisit the `faultString` again, "`parse error. not well formed`", it may be more clear now that the error of a not well-formed document must be reported.

As this is in context of XMLRPC, it should be clear by now that the XML document is the actual request you've send to the server and already that request as a whole document does not compute, not a specific method-name or other detail there-in.

---

**TLDR:** The request you're sending is not a well-formed XML document. Such requests will always result in an error with standard XML processors.

Revisit how you create such requests, according to your question all of your requests are returning this error, so you should check your general procedure creating a request. Perhaps use an XML/XMLRPC validation facility before sending requests to the concrete server.

---

**Additional Q&A Material**

- [Wordpress XML-RPC POST returning -32700 error with php-xml extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55056268/367456)